Plotshape() function
The plotshape() function does not show the markings it shows in replay mode after exiting the mode.example chart here ->
[dxl,dxh,dxl1,dxh1]=request.security(sym,"1D",[low,high,low[1],high[1]],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

Could my use of lookahead in the code be incorrect?
Thank you for your help in this matter.
